# Data Visualization using react

Tags: reactjs

I guess react can do what i want. I have a problem statement in which I need to visualize data obtained from processes. The data that needs to be visualized needs some pre-processing. I need to visualize multiple sequences with each sequence having multiple processes in it. Each process varies in time duration, which have to be represented in form of array of varying length. Also in order to manage 1000's of sequences I need to do some clustering and represent fewer sequences that fits on single page. I am looking to find the best suited framework in JS to achieve this. Can anyone please guide me.

[image]

Comment: I use [dc.js](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/) for data visualization, very nice.

Comment: use d3.js for data visualization